# disable cursor color in putty client ssh terminal when in vi

Tags: vim, vimrc, cursor, syntax-highlighting

I use `putty.exe` in windows 7 to connect to my Linux system.
I use **vi**.  I would like the cursor in `vi` to remain white all the time, and not change to green or blue around my if statement {  }  brackets while editing .c files.  The background color in the putty ssh window is black, all the text is white, and when the cursor decides to highlight green and blue about things it hurts more than it helps.  and it's not just the location of the cursor but it will highlight characters that are elsewhere nearby... like with if statement if I have something like

```
if ( a == b )
{
}
```

the `{` and `}` will get highlighted while typing and makes it very hard to tell where my cursor is positioned, because I cannot easily tell the difference between the colors.

I have edited `/etc/bash.bashrc`  and  `/etc/csh.cshrc`  and commented out the color options for the `ls` command,
and have edited my my `~/.vimrc`  file and have  `syntax off` as the first line with nothing else below.  But the cursor and text highlighting persists in `vi`,  how do I fully disable that?
thanks.

Comment: Just give a try, use `vim` instead of `vi`

Comment: vim does the same thing  :(

Comment: and this is in Novel SLES 11.4 x86-64

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_turn_off_all_colors

edited my ~/.vimrc  file and have this in there,
my cursor color is still green but that's acceptable, the character highlighting no longer happens.

```
syntax off
set nohlsearch
set t_Co=0
```

Answer (score 0):

The article [Customizing/disabling VIM’s matching parenthesis highlighting](http://design.liberta.co.za/articles/customizing-disabling-vim-matching-parenthesis-highlighting/) gives some suggestions.  The simplest one is to add this to your `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:loaded_matchparen=1
```

That leaves the syntax highlighting alone.